# PowerBI-JavaScript setAccessToken doesn't work

Tags: javascript, powerbi-embedded

I'm using **PowerBI-JavaScript** library to embed the dashboard on my website :

```
var config = {
    type: 'dashboard',
    tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
    accessToken: accessToken,
    embedUrl: embedUrl,
    id: embedDashboardId
};

// Get a reference to the embedded dashboard HTML element
var dashboardContainer = $('#dashboardContainer')[0];

// Embed the dashboard and display it within the div container.
var dashboard = powerbi.embed(dashboardContainer, config);
```

I wanna use `setAccessToken` to update my AccessToken keeping dashboard not expired, so I make function below :

```
function setToken() {

    dashboard.setAccessToken("newtoken")
        .then(function (r) {
            console.log(r);
            console.log("Update success!!")
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            console.error('Error setting access token', e);
        });

}
```

I can see **"Update success!!"** on console. But when I use `getAccessToken()`, AccessToken is same as before. It didn't update my AccessToken!!

Please give me a advise or solution to fix this problem! I would appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it !How you can see at the code in the lib, when you set the new access token it send it to the service, and apparently does not store your token:

```
Embed.prototype.setAccessToken = function (accessToken) {
        var embedType = this.config.type;
        return this.service.hpm.post('/' + embedType + '/token', accessToken, { uid: this.config.uniqueId }, this.iframe.contentWindow)
            .then(function (response) {
            return response.body;
        })
            .catch(function (response) {
            throw response.body;
        });
    };
```

And when you call getAccessToken it will return the token wich you provided first in the config object (if it is lazy evaluated, as I think it is):

```
Embed.prototype.getAccessToken = function (globalAccessToken) {
        var accessToken = this.config.accessToken || this.element.getAttribute(Embed.accessTokenAttribute) || globalAccessToken;
        if (!accessToken) {
            throw new Error("No access token was found for element. You must specify an access token directly on the element using attribute '" + Embed.accessTokenAttribute + "' or specify a global token at: powerbi.accessToken.");
        }
        return accessToken;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually see requests going out with the old access token after calling SetAccessToken? 
Having GetAccessToken returning wrong result after calling SetAccessToken is a bug in the javascript SDK